# invalid request unexpected eof laravel

Tags: laravel, eof

Hi guys just want to know what does this error mean? I keep getting `127.0.0.1:54282 invalid request (unexpected eof)` , what should I do? My view shows everything normal and I don't think there should be any wrong in my codes as well. And also 54282 is that suppose to be a port?

Comment: Where do you get this error message? Where does this port come from? Please provide more details like log files and co.

Comment: @mrHooty, I got this when I run the php artisan serve command and I am not even sure if 54282 is the port

Comment: @blastme your assumption about 54282 is right this is a port. this is the local address for TCP protocol for requesting and responsing over the server

Comment: @HardikaSatasiya but why does it point me to that port? I don't think there should be any problem there

Comment: @blastme, within config/database, check your port number. MySQL is generally 3306